# Non-decimal representation of solutions of cubic equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a cubic equation as follows

```
Solve[2 (Sqrt[x])^3 - 1.5*x^0.5*vd == 2 (Sqrt[\[Eta]0])^3, {x}]
```

I want to get the solution of $x$ in terms of $\eta_0 $, with rational/irrational factors, and then in the limit $vd<<\eta_0, x$ get the solution.
When I try to use solve, I get solution like this

[image] 
since I am trying to solve an analytical physical equation, I want to get the pre-factors right in terms of actual numbers (rational or irrational) and not their decimal values (like $\sqrt{2}$ instead of 1.414 and $\frac{3}{5}$ instead of 0.6 in the pre factors.

Comment: Replace 1.5 with 3/2 and 0.5 with 1/2 in your equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a series expansion for small `vd` directly with [`AsymptoticSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve.html): Assuming you want the real-valued branch,

```
AsymptoticSolve[2 (Sqrt[x])^3 - 3/2*Sqrt[x]*vd == 2 (Sqrt[η0])^3, {x, η0}, {vd, 0, 4}]
```

> {{x -> vd/2 - vd^3/(96 η0^2) + vd^2/(16 η0) + η0}}

Comment: You don't need  `AsymptoticSolve`. Try `Solve[2 (Sqrt[x])^3 - 1.5*x^0.5*vd == 2 (Sqrt[\[Eta]0])^3 // 
  Rationalize, {x}]` (see comment  @Lotus)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann as the OP is after the limiting behavior for small `vd` the idea here was to present the new version 12 functionality that not everybody has seen yet.